# Jquery format Number to 4 digits including Colon

Tags: jquery, numbers, format

My script receives values 'of time' but in various formats:

```
    100
    0143
    0015
    1127
    1300
    1230
    2258
    etc...
```

I'm trying to find a way to convert that to always be 4 digits and then include a colon between the second and third digits. eg:

```
100 becomes 01:00
0143 becomes 01:43
0015 becomes 00:15
2258 becomes 22:58 etc
```

Can anyone advise the best way to do this ?

I was thinking of working backwards, strip the last 2 digits, prepend with : and pad the remaining if needed.

But that seems wrong !

Thanks

update..

This seems to work:

```
var time = ("0000" + timer).slice(-4)
time = time.substr(0,2) + ":" + time.substr(2);
```

Comment: *"But that seems wrong"* ... why? Did you even try it? Should try things first. Then ask questions showing the code that isn't working as expected

Comment: Yes it did try it, but I couldn't get it to work. I've now got it working.. I'll update my original question with a working solution.

Comment: ("000" + time).slice(-4).substr(0,2) + ":" +("000" + time).slice(-2);

Answer (score 2):

I personally think there's nothing wrong with your implementation. It's simple and does what it's supposed to do. For inserting the colon character, you can also use JavaScript's built-in [replace()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) and regular expressions:

```
var n = 100;
('0000' + n.toString()).
  slice(-4).
  replace(/(\d{2})(\d{2})$/, '$1:$2');   // => '01:00'
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple code to achieve what you want. But you already have updated your question with a working code and clearly that code is much better and compact.

```js
// This code is only for demo
var timeStrings = ["100", "0120", "2354" ];
timeStrings.forEach(function( timeString ){
  console.log( returnFormattedTime( timeString ) );
});//forEach()


// here is the function that formats these time strings
function returnFormattedTime( timeString ){
  // pad with zero first if required
  var unformattedTime = timeString;
  var numZeroes = 4 - unformattedTime.length;
  if( numZeroes > 0 ){
    var zeroPadding = "";
    for( var i = 0; i < numZeroes; i++ ){
      zeroPadding += "0";
    }//for()
    unformattedTime = zeroPadding + unformattedTime;
  }//if()

  var formattedTime = unformattedTime[0]+unformattedTime[1]+":"+unformattedTime[2]+unformattedTime[3];
  return formattedTime;
  
}//returnFormattedTime()
```